# How do I use a datetime.date value in apache beam GroupBy?

Tags: python, typeerror, apache-beam

I am trying to use apache beam's [`beam.GroupBy(...)`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/groupby/) construct, and running into a problem with it not knowing how to encode a standard python `datetime.date`.

Here's a simplified code chunk demonstrating the issue. The code:

```py
import logging
import random
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from datetime import date


def random_record():
    return {
        'account_id'   : random.randint(1004, 1009),
        'activity_date': date(2021, 10, random.randint(1, 4)),
        'region'       : random.randint(30, 40),
        'largest_sale' : random.randint(10000, 40000),
        'total_sales'  : random.randint(100000, 900000)
    }

def main(argv=None):
    random.seed(2349090823434)

    records = [random_record() for i in range(100)]

    with beam.Pipeline() as p:
        output = (
            p 
            | "Source" >> beam.Create(records)
            | "Typed"  >> beam.Map(lambda d: beam.Row(**d))
            | "Rollup" >> (beam.GroupBy('account_id', 'activity_date')
                                .aggregate_field('total_sales', sum, 'total_sales')
                                .aggregate_field('largest_sale', max, 'largest_sale')
                        )
            | "Output" >> WriteToText('learn-output', file_name_suffix='.csv')
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    main()
```

When I run this:

```sh
% python learn.py
```

Results in the error:

```
WARNING:apache_beam.coders.coder_impl:Using fallback deterministic coder for type '<class 'apache_beam.transforms.core.Key'>' in 'Rollup/CombinePerKey(TupleCombineFn)/GroupByKey'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: Unable to deterministically encode '2021-10-01' of type '<class 'datetime.date'>', please provide a type hint for the input of 'Rollup/CombinePerKey(TupleCombineFn)/GroupByKey'

...

TypeError: Unable to deterministically encode 'Key(account_id=1007, activity_date=datetime.date(2021, 10, 1))' of type '<class 'apache_beam.transforms.core.Key'>', 
please provide a type hint for the input of 'Rollup/CombinePerKey(TupleCombineFn)/GroupByKey'
```

I am wondering how to actually "provide a type hint for the input of 'Rollup/CombinePerKey(TupleCombineFn)/GroupByKey'".

It seems like the `GroupByKey` is being called within `GroupBy`. So I either need to tell GroupBy how to handle my 2-tuple key, or perhaps register some coder to support `datetime.date`...

Comment: We're encountering the exact same problem, and simply decreasing our `beam` version fixes the problem :( I strongly suspect this is simply a bug and not expected behavior.

Comment: We've logged this as a bug in beam: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-13166

Answer (score 2):

Generally you should be able to do something like

```
class DateCoder(beam.coders.Coder):
    def encode(self, d):
        return d.isoformat().encode('ascii')
    def decode(self, bs):
        return datetime.date.fromisoformat(bs.decode('ascii'))
    def is_deterministic(self):
        return True

beam.coders.registry.register_coder(date, DateCoder)
```

to handle this, but there is some poor interactions with schemas here that make it harder to use `beam.GroupBy` in this case. One issue is that `beam.Row(**d)` doesn't actually let Beam figure out the column name/types (schema) of these `Row` objects at construction time (for that you need to pass keywords explicitly). (Future work to make this work better.)

Definitely converting to strings is as the comment suggested is a simple option here.

Answer (score 0):

You could just convert the date to a string for grouping purposes:

```
beam.GroupBy('account_id', date_str=lambda x: str(x.activity_date))
```

Comment: I'm new to apache beam, so I'm wondering whether this is idiomatic (as in, how experienced users recommend doing this), or whether this is a work around.

Because essentially, the `str( )` is being using as a coder here, right?

Comment: @DilumRanatunga tbh I've barely used it myself; a little documentation perusal indicates you could potentially do something with defining a custom `Coder` and passing it to `registry.register_coder` along with potentially defining `with_input_types` and/or `with_output_types` on the pipeline, but I took a few stabs at it and couldn't get it working.

Comment: thanks for trying things on my behalf. I was in the same board re: custom coders. The docs drop off very quickly, and I was wading through 2000+ line python files.